# How to bulk load relations in sqlalchemy for a subset of parents?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Let's say I have two models Blog and Comment with a one to many relationship.

```
class Blog(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    comments = relationship("Comment")

class Comment(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    blog = relationship("Blog")
```

I can efficiently query blogs along with their comments with a subquery like so

```
session.query(Blog).filter(...filter_criteria...).options(subqueryload(Blog.comments)).all()
```

This emits two separate queries - one to load blogs and another to load comments.

How do I load comments if I already have a bunch of blog objects already queried? The reason I can't use subqueryload while fetching blogs is there is application logic that uses a subset blogs whose comments are required.

In other words, if I have 5 blog objects in a list, is there a way to load comments efficiently so I can access them this way:

```
blogs = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]
# Do something here to efficiently load comments
for blog in blogs:
    blog.comments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have already have loaded the Blog objects, then to be 'efficient' you should emit at most 1 more query to load these blog object's comments.

```
blogs = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]
blog_ids = [blog.id for blog in blogs]    
comments = session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.blog_id.in_(blog_ids)).all()
```

This assumes `blog_id` is the fk column on `Comment`.

SQLAlchemy keeps tracks of all objects you load during a given transaction and will not emit query's to load objects which have already been loaded. This is done using the [Identity Map Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)

Check out this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337933/how-to-explicitly-load-relationships-on-an-existing-object) and it's answers.

Note that using this 'in_' clause may or may not the most efficient query depending on your schema and how many blog_ids your passing, but its probably as preformant as you need it to be.